# pandas sort values to get top 5 for each column in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with city, name and members. I need to find the top 5 groups (name) in terms of highest member ('members') count per city.

This is what I get when I use:

`clust.groupby(['city','name']).agg({'members':sum})`

`members
city                                   name 
Bath         AWS Bath User Group        346
             Agile Bath & Bristol        957
Bath         Crypto Chat                 47
Bath         JS                          142
Bath         Machine Learning Meetup     435
Belfast      4th Industrial Revolution Challenge    609
Belfast      Adobe Meetup                         66
Belfast      Azure Meetup                        205
Southampton  Crypto Currency Trading SouthCoast 50
Southampton Bitcoin and Altcoin Meetup          50
Southampton Functional Programming Meetup       28
Southampton Virtual Reality Meetup              248
Sunderland  Sunderland Digital  287`

I need the top 5 but as you can see the member count doesn't seem to be ordered, i.e. 346 before 957 etc.

I've also tried sorting the values before-hand and do:

`clust.sort_values(['city', 'name'], axis=0).groupby('city').head(5)`

But that returns a similar series.

I've used this one too `clust.groupby(['city', 'name']).head(5)`

but it gives me all the rows and not top 5. It also isn't structured so not in alphabetical order.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think need add `ascending=[True, False]` to [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and change column to `members` for sorting:

```
clust = clust.groupby(['city','name'], as_index=False)['members'].sum()
df = clust.sort_values(['city', 'members'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('city').head(5)
print (df)

           city                                 name  members
1          Bath                 Agile Bath & Bristol      957
4          Bath              Machine Learning Meetup      435
0          Bath                  AWS Bath User Group      346
3          Bath                                   JS      142
2          Bath                          Crypto Chat       47
5       Belfast  4th Industrial Revolution Challenge      609
7       Belfast                         Azure Meetup      205
6       Belfast                         Adobe Meetup       66
11  Southampton               Virtual Reality Meetup      248
8   Southampton   Crypto Currency Trading SouthCoast       50
9   Southampton           Bitcoin and Altcoin Meetup       50
10  Southampton        Functional Programming Meetup       28
12   Sunderland                   Sunderland Digital      287
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly. one question: what does the `ascending =[True, False]` do? exactly @jezrael

Comment: @snow_fall - It sort first column `city` ascending and then `members` descending

Comment: Aaah perfect! Great to know- Thanks! I have another question... how did you sort out the df making it indexed and structured like that? @jezrael

Comment: @snow_fall show your data clearly next time , and well explain the problem will be a big help for us

Comment: @snow_fall - Do you need `MultiIndex` ? then add `df = df.set_index(['city','name'])`

Comment: @jezrael not like that. I meant simply within your answer, how did you structure the mess of a dataframe I put there in my question?

Comment: @snow_fall - Is possible use my all solution instead all code in your answer?

Comment: @jezrael I don't want to use it as a solution we've misunderstood one another. I want to understand how I can formulate better questions next time and make my dataframe have an index like the one you have in the red there. But never mind, thank you for the answer.